# Retrieving data from Radio Buttons

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I need to retrieve data from radio buttons.

Basically like this:

```
String Gender = rdbtnM.getText();
```

My problem is, the user can select from one of 2 radio buttons:
rdbtnM and rdbtnF. So the String Gender should have the value whatever has been chosen; F or M.

How do I write that?
I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
String Gender - rdbtnM.getText(); && rdbtnF.getText();
```

Comment: Is that a real cut/paste of your code?  if so, it's no wonder it doesn't work.

Comment: no my code is obviously longer, but i just wrote the code here, to show how to retrieve data from a radio button?

Comment: You have a `=` in the first line and a `-` in the second immediately after `Gender`.  Then you have a `;` before the `&&` in the second.  See what I'm getting at?

Comment: Okay, so String Gender = rdbtnM.getText() && rdbtnF.getText();

THIS STILL DOESNT WORK THOUGH :(

Comment: I'm a pedant about this because running around solving problems with code that's not the real, running, failing code is an exercise in futility.

Comment: "Anding" two Strings? It is strange to me!

Answer (score 4):

Don't give the radio buttons an ActionListener. One way to get the result is to query the ButtonGroup that controls the RadioButton. If you've given each JRadioButton an appropriate actionCommand then the ButtonModel returned by the ButtonGroup will hold that String.  For example, please have a look at the sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6088833/522444).

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is global, implement an action listener to both radio buttons that triggers when a user toggles either one. Within the action listener method, set the string Gender to the appropriate value as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(radiomale.isSelected())
String gender="male";
if(femaleradio.isSelected())
String gender="female";
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit more

Comment: radiomale is the name of object of the radio button with male  and radiofemale is the name of object of the radio button with female. So if  the male is selected   then gender = male . if  female is selected  then gender = female